# How to use generics?

Tags: java, generics

I have the following method in my class :

```
public void insert(E item)
{
    assert this.listSize < this.maxSize : "Error : List capacity exceeded.";

    for (int i = this.listSize; i > this.curr; i--)
    {
        this.listArray[i] = this.listArray[i-1];
    }

    this.listArray[this.curr] = item;

    this.listSize++;
}
```

All it really does it take in an element, and add it to an ArrayList.

But what I want to know, is how I actually call this method?

For example - in an application - I create the Array list as follows :

```
// Create instance of ArrayList
ArrayList myArrayList = new ArrayList();

// Call insert to add to the list...
myArrayList.insert(WHAT GOES IN HERE?);
```

I have tried adding simple integers and strings in, I am really just missing something stupid.

Comment: Is `ArrayList` an instance of `java.util.ArrayList` or your own class?  How is the class defined?  What does `<E>` actually mean?

Comment: In your example you create `ArrayList` as a [Raw Type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look like you have created a custom class `ArrayList`. If yes, you need to parametrized your class, example below

```
public class ArrayList<E>
```

Then you can call `insert` like below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        list.insert(123);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! This is what I was looking for! :)